# Finding the column number of the String that needs to be found in Java using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Suppose I need to find the String "XXX" in an Excel sheet, I am not aware of how to get the column number and row number of the cell which contains the string.

```
Iterator<Row> it = XXXPresentSheet.iterator();          
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Row row = it.next();                
    Iterator<Cell> cellIter = row.cellIterator();

    while (cellIter.hasNext()) {
        String field1 = cellIter.next().getStringCellValue();               
        if (field1 == "XXX") {
            System.out.println(someMethodThatReturnsColumnNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to traverse through the row using the cell iterator. But when I encounter the String which I want, I want to get that column number. Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate [Link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049995/java-poi-how-to-find-an-excel-cell-with-a-string-value-and-get-its-position-ro)

Comment: You can use a simple counter that increases upon each `it.next()` while loop iteration.

Comment: `field1 == "XXX"`is not going to work the way you probably expect it to. Use `equals` to compare.

Comment: @f_puras The code will also fail for non-string cells (eg numeric ones). [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31859798/685641) has a fix for both those issues :)

Comment: @Gagravarr I see. Strange you're getting downvoted for an answer which looks reasonable to me...

Comment: @f_puras Such is the joy of the internet - an answer with clear problems gets upvotes, and one which works + fixes the next two problems the OP will hit, written by one of the people who helps maintain the library in question, gets downvoted... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask a cell nicely, it will [tell you what Column Number it is in](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex%28%29). It will also tell you [what Row Number it is in](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getRowIndex%28%29)

So, just do something like:

```
DataFormatter fmt = new DataFormatter();
for (Row r : sheet) {
   for (Cell c : r) {
       if ("ThingToLookFor".equals(fmt.formatCellValue(cell))) {
          // Found it!
          int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex();
          int rowNumber = c.getRowNumber();
          // Get the Excel style reference, eg C12
          String ref = ((new CellReference(rowNumber,columnIndex)).formatAsString();
       }
   }
}
```

By using a `DataFormatter`, you can get the string value to compare for any cell, not just String ones. The `CellReference` bit is optional, but'll help if you want to see the Excel-style reference for the cell that matched

Comment: Thank a lot @Gagravarr. Your solution woks perfectly :)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way to do this is to implement your own variable which will increase on each successful iteration of the `while(it.hasNext())` loop.

```
Iterator<Row> it = XXXPresentSheet.iterator();  
while(it.hasNext()) { 
    int column = 0;
    Row row = it.next();                
    Iterator<Cell> cellIter = row.cellIterator();
    while(cellIter.hasNext()) {
       column++;
       String field1 = cellIter.next().getStringCellValue();                
       if(field1 == "XXX") {
           System.out.println(column);
       }
    }
}
```

Where `column = 1` (starting column), you can increment column AFTER the first loop if you wish to start with the value `column = 0`

Further reading [can be found in this alternative StackOverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329842/how-to-get-the-current-loop-index-when-using-iterator)

Comment: The above method works like a charm for getting the row number. Although for finding the column number of the cell has a small problem since the excelsheet has empty columns among. Is there a way to overcome that??

Comment: Woops. I accidentally iterated the wrong thing. Iterate the cell rather than row! My mistake! Updated now. :)

Comment: I realized the issue before itself. Thanks anyway. But now the problem is cellIter.next() method is not taking into account the empty cells. So the empty columns are left uncounted. Any workaround for this?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure sorry, it's not an ideal solution that's for sure.

Comment: It's alright. Thank you so much for ur time. I deeply appreciate it insidesin :)

Comment: The iterator skips over blank cells, so this solution is incorrect as it'd give the wrong column number for cells after that point

Comment: It's not an incorrect solution. Just not the solution to that particular context.

Comment: It is an incorrect solution, you claim that an iterator index will give you the column, but in many cases it won't do as the iterator skips blank cells. The correct solution is to ask the cell what column it's in!

Comment: Nope, it was not. Unfortunate that you would think that way though. :(

Comment: Your answer will only work if the string in question is in any cells before blank ones, and therefore is not a general answer as it'll fail in any case with blank cells before the needed one, and as the OP has pointed out won't work for them. There is a simple way to do it that doesn't have your issues! Your code will also fail to match the string (== doesn't do what you think for strings), and will fail for non-string cells (eg numeric ones). That's quite a lot wrong :(

Comment: Correct. Which is a solution to those tables with no blank cells. Glad you agree with me finally.